# How to tag fragments using hide/show?

Tags: android, transactions, android-fragments, tags

in my app i have been using add/replace to transact my fragments. To find the unique references lateron for checking which view is active, i tagged them like this:

```
fm.beginTransaction()
  .replace(R.id.customer_details_fragment, fragment, "MyUniqueTag")
  .commit();
```

now i read some more details on how the fragments work and i figured that i should use hide/show for the fragment-transaction because its saving alot of cpu-load if you just have to re-draw the views.

**My question is**: 
Does it make sense to use tags in context with hide/show aswell and if so, how do i tag them?

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.show(fragment);
                ft.hide(fragment);
                ft.commit();
```

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if it could help you.

Comment: but it didn't reaaly answer my question :/

Comment: Just tag them as usual. Or do I understand you wrong? In this case, please be more specific :D

Answer (score 0):

["Shows a previously hidden fragment. This is only relevant for fragments whose views have been added to a container."](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#show%28android.app.Fragment%29) - To use this function you must also add the fragment to a container. So you can set a tag at this point as usual.